# Openvpn is not ussing correct certificate

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

i have problem with setting openvpn. I have receive installator file which also adds certs. I select "strong private key protecion" so system should ask me everytime openvpn tries to use that certificate. But when i want to connect to the VPN server there  is no prompt from system. So i guess that openvpn is trying to use wrong certificate and thats why it cannot establish connection. I'm sure that cert names provided in the config are correct

Comment: Is OpenVPN table to read the cert - especially the private key?  What does the debug output say?

Comment: @davidgo Fri Apr 20 11:14:09 2018 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Fri Apr 20 11:14:09 2018 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Fri Apr 20 11:14:09 2018 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting